# Childrens Alphabetical Woodblocks Font

Tags: fonts, font-identification, images, free

I am looking for a font or image with woodblock style blocks that I can type in. Like children's blocks similar to the ones in this picture:

[image: Children's Wooden Blocks].

Any ideas where I can find some?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't simply purchase the image at Dreamstime.com which you've used as a sample? Dreamstime.com sells high resolution images. Kind of bad form to say.. "Here's what I want.. but I don't want to pay $5 for it." And ask others to search for a free alternative.

Comment: My answer to questions like this is "Buy the damn blocks and use your camera." You want a rice texture? Scan some rice. You want a leaf pattern? Photograph actual leaves. People go overboard in faking when just getting the real thing is sometimes pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

P22 has a font mirrored after these type of toy blocks called Toy Box Blocks:

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/p22/toybox-blocks/

[image]